# Использование русских символов в socket python 2.7

Tags: сокет, unicode, python-2.7

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
В python 2.7 с помощью socket.send() нужно отправить строку вида

> "id:{id}, first_name:{Имя}, last_name:{Фамилия}"

При выполнении получаю ошибку:

> 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 20-26: ordinal not
>   in range(128)

Подскажите, как запихнуть в сокет юникод-строку или корректно кодировать эту?

Comment: В сокетах нет символов, в сокетах есть только байты. Для того, чтобы передать по сокетам символы, нужно закодировать их в байты каким-то образом. В своём ответе вы закодировали символы в байты, используя кодировку utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

Все решалось очень просто: нужно было дописать encode('utf-8')